# Accessing the Created By coloumn value in event receiver(item added) sharepoint 2010

Tags: list, event-receivers

Hi I am trying to access the created by coloumn in item added event reciever.But when i debug it shows null value...below is the code

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
   var CreatedBy = (string)properties.AfterProperties["Author"];
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using ListItem instead of AfterProperties

```
var CreatedBy = (string)properties.ListItem["Author"];
```

I believe the AfterProperties are for the synchronous events (end in ING - e.g. Adding, Deleting, etc.)

Furthermore you can get an SPUser object from this. Refer to the following site for details on how that might be done. Once you have an SPUser object you have access to all sorts of useful properties such as Name, Email, and more.

- http://aarohblah.blogspot.com/2009/11/converting-list-item-to-spuser-object.html

Comment: I i am getting the CreatedBy value as 9;#domain/username ..i am little confuse  as to from where the value 9;# is coming from?

Comment: A user field like that is essentially a lookup to the users list within the SharePoint Site Collection. 9 is the id of the user in the list, the ;# is a separator (and is the syntax used for all lookup fields) and domain\username is the value of the lookup.

Comment: @spStacker you can parse lookup field by using following code fragments: `var id = new SPFieldLookupValue(fieldValue).LookupId` and `var value = new SPFieldLookupValue(fieldValue).LookupValue`

Comment: No Problem! I updated my answer with a link on how you can get an SPUser object from that value as well.

Comment: Excellent, Thanks guys for such prompt and detailed help!

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to access the value in the specific field?
if so, try something like this:

```
using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["yourListHere"];
                SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is use the property `UserLoginName`, that returns the user login which fires the event, example below:

```
SPUser authorUser = web.EnsureUser(properties.UserLoginName);

//properties is the SPItemEventProperties properties
//SPWeb is properties.OpenWeb();
```